# Read qr code from large image

Tags: c#, qr-code, zxing

I have an image which has qr code. It is 15MB color image. I am using `zxing` library but it taking too much time to read the qr code.

How can reduce the time how effectively read the qr code image? Here is my code:

```
IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();

for (int i = 100; i < img.Width; i++)
{
   for (int j = 100; j < img.Height; j++)
   {
       imgw = i; imgh = j;
       Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img, imgw, imgh);
       Qrresult = reader.Decode(bmp);
       if (Qrresult != null)
       {
           QRcodevalue = Qrresult.Text;
           bmp.Dispose();
           img.Dispose();
           return QRcodevalue;
       }
       j = j + 100;
       bmp.Dispose();
    }
    i = i + 100;
}
```

[This is my sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFQRU.jpg)